# Алгоритмом проверки возможности сортировки некоторого набора чисел

Tags: c++, алгоритм, сортировка, олимпиада

Есть задача, суть которой сводится к проверке возможности сортировки некоторого набора чисел. Если сортировка возможно то вывести YES, в противном случае NO.

> k-сортировка
>
> В этом году Гриша поступил в Университет ИТ. В Университете ИТ очень много новых предметов, интересных и не очень. Особенно Грише нравится предмет "Алгоритмы и структуры данных". На последней лекции были рассказаны алгоритмы сортировки. Гриша - очень амбициозный молодой человек и хочет изобрести свой алгоритм, который впоследствии будет назван именем его любимого дедушки. Вдохновившись чтением многотомника Кнута, Гриша решил модернизировать какой-нибудь уже существующий алгоритм сортировки натуральных чисел, наложив следующее ограничение. Любые два элемента можно менять местами, только если они сравнимы по модулю некоторого натурального числа k, то есть дают одинаковые остатки при делении на k. Но все инновационные методы требуют проверки, поэтому Гриша обратился за помощью к Вам!
>
> Проверьте, сможет ли новая версия алгоритма отсортировать заданный массив натуральных чисел.
>
> Входные данные
>
> Первая строка входного файла содержит два числа n (1 ≤ n ≤ 1000) и k (1 ≤ k ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>) - количество элементов в массиве и число, по модулю которого сравниваются элементы массива.
>
> Вторая строка входного файла содержит n целых чисел ai - элементы массива (1 ≤ ai ≤ 10<sup>9</sup>).
>
> Выходные данные
>
> В выходной файл выведите YES, если алгоритм сможет отсортировать заданный массив и NO - в обратном случае.

Собственно, это сам текст задачи. Тестовые данные такие:

```
5 2 
1 2 3 4 5 - результат YES

3 2 
2 3 1 - результат NO.
```

Мой алгоритм решения задачи следующий

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
 int n = 0;
 int k = 0;
 int *array;
 cin >> n;
 if (n == 1) {
    cout << "YES" << endl;
    return 0;
 }

 cin >> k;

 if (k == 1) {
    cout << "YES" << endl;
    return 0;
 }

 array = new int[n];

 for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
    cin >> array[i];
 }

 int afterTemp = 0;
 int beforeTemp = 0;
 afterTemp = array[0] % k;
 beforeTemp = array[1] % k;
 bool switchMod = true;

 for (int i = 2; i < n; ++i) {
    if (switchMod) {
        if (array[i] % k == afterTemp) {
            switchMod = false;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
    else {
        if (array[i] % k == beforeTemp) {
            switchMod = true;
        }
        else {
            cout << "NO" << endl;
            return 0;
        }
    }
 }
 cout << "YES" << endl;
 return 0;
}
```

В тестирующей системе прохожу только половину правильных ответов (53%). Если у кого то есть идеи, что я мог упустить, подскажите пожалуйста.

Comment: Ссылку на тестирующую систему можно попросить?

Comment: Да, конечно http://www.e-olymp.com/ru/problems/2778

Answer (score 3):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int A[1111],B[1111];

int main(){
  int N,K;
  cin >> N >> K;
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++){
     cin >> A[i];
     B[i] = A[i];
  }
  sort(A,A+N);
  for (int i=0;i<N;i++)
    if (A[i] % K != B[i] % K){
         cout << "NO";
         return 0; 
    }
 cout << "YES";
}
```

Например так.
Заметим, что мы можем менять как угодно элементы с одинаковым остатком от деления на K. Поэтому остаток от деления на K числа в каждой позиции не меняется. Отсортируем и проверим что это так. Если не так, то ответ нет. Иначе да.

Answer (score 1):

Просто проверяя последовательность остатков от деления невозможно определить возможно ли отсортировать последовательность чисел или нет, потому что одна и также последовательность остатков соответствует разным числовым последовательностям, например:

Последовательность чисел: 6 3 4 9 при k = 2 дает последовательность остатков 0101 и отсортировать ее нельзя поскольку 9 и 6 местами не поменять (разные остатки).

Последовательность чисел: 6 5 4 3 при k = 2 дает туже последовательность остатков 0101 при этом исходная последовательность уже отсортирована.

Поэтому чередование остатков ничего не определит. В условии не оговорена сложность решения, и при таком ограничении количества элементов 0 < n < 1000 можно попробовать просто модифицировать одну из простых сортировок (пузырек, выборка и т.п. O(N2))

Вот я немного модифицировал сортировку выборкой, но прогон на e-olymp дал, как ни странно, те же 53%, причем я потом попробовал в одном месте поменять NO на YES и опять получил 53%:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctype.h>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
     int n = 0;
     int k = 0;
     int *array;
     cin >> n;
     if (n == 1) {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
        return 0;
     }

     cin >> k;

     if (k == 1) {
        cout << "YES" << endl;
        return 0;
     }

     array = new int[n];

     for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cin >> array[i];
     }

     int temp;
     int pointerMax = 0;
     int pointerMin = 0;

     for (int i = 0; i < n - i; i++) {
         pointerMax = i;
         pointerMin = i;
         for (int j = i + 1; j < n - i; j++) {
            if (array[j] < array[pointerMin]) {
                pointerMin = j;
            }
            if(array[j] > array[pointerMax]) {
                pointerMax = j;
            }
         }

         if (array[i] % k != array[pointerMax] % k) {
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
            return 0;
         }

         temp = array[pointerMax];
         array[pointerMax] = array[i];
         array[i] = temp;
         pointerMin =  (pointerMin == i) ? pointerMax: pointerMin;

         if (array[n - (i + 1)] % k != array[pointerMin] % k) {
            cout<<"NO"<<endl;
            return 0;
         }

         temp = array[pointerMin];
         array[pointerMin] = array[n - (i + 1)];
         array[n - (i + 1)] = temp;

     }
     cout << "YES" << endl;
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Что-то сложно...

Comment: Да это на первый взгляд:) Обычная сортировка выборкой. На каждом проходе выбирается максимальный и минимальный элемент. Так как последовательность остатков не должна измениться то максимальный элемент должен иметь такой же остаток, что и элемент в крайней левой позиции (сортируем по убыванию), а минимальный такой же остаток как и элемент в крайней правой. Проверяем и если это не так значит отсортировать нельзя, иначе сужаем диапазон поиска и ищем новую пару. Я не уверен, что при решении можно использовать библиотечные методы, а так конечно предыдущий ответ намного лаконичнее, но смысл тот же.

Comment: В олимпиадных задачах всегда можно использовать библиотечные методы. Кроме многопоточности.